# object .... in GTM variables. How?

Tags: google-tag-manager

GTM has elements that do not have #identifiers and #classes for variables http://prntscr.com/q2qqen

Few GTM has elements that have with value:

```
[object SVGAnimatedString]
[object SVGSVGElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLdivElement]
[object HTMLBodyElement]
```

etc

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understand your question, but these are DOM elements.

The DOM is the document object model, a tree-like structure that contains the elements your webpage is made of - you have a body element (HTMLBodyElement) that contains e.g. one or more div elements (HTMLdivElement) etc.

The GTM click handler will always return the element that the current user has clicked on.

DOM elements are objects. They are hard to represent in text form (since they have properties, and methods, and are derived from parent objects and may have child nodes etc), so the browser tries to tell you what kind of object is returned - e.g. and HTML element of the div type (HTMLdivElement) or a scalable vector graphic (SVGSVGElement) etc.

That they do not have classes or ids has nothing to do with GTM, it just happened that the user clicked on elements that do not have id or class attributes.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sometimes an element has a class and an identifier (for example, a form), but when the trigger is configured, it does not work. It seems that I am clinging to that element. Can you somehow understand which element is the main, which is the child, and how to correctly find classes and identifiers?

Comment: Example - i have form on site http://prntscr.com/q3jtbl She is have id and class. I configure the trigger for the class and identifier, but after the form is submitted, the trigger does not work

Comment: The most likely explanation is that there are nested elements, and that  the clicked element is actually some nested element that does not have the id, but that is really hard to tell from a screenshot.

Comment: That is, I need to look for a class or identifier on level higher or lower element? Need to look for the last nesting element or the first element (parents)? Sorry for abstraction.